# Undefined symbol: apr_crypto_init during Apache restart?

Tags: apache, svn, centos

I attempted to update my version of SVN from 1.7 to 1.8 as per this guide:
http://snippets.khromov.se/subversion-1-8-centos-6/

All seemed to install fine, however now I have an issue when I try to restart Apache:
    /usr/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/httpd: undefined symbol: apr_crypto_init

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Which packages need to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue after installing some perl modules.

I did the following to resolve it:

```
yum remove vulture-common-3.2-185.1.x86_64

cd /usr/lib

ln -sf libaprutil-1.so.0.2.9 libaprutil-1.so.0

ln -sf libapr-1.so.0.2.9 libapr-1.so.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`apr_crypto_init` is new with APR-Util 1.4.x.  CentOS 6 should already have APR-Util 1.4.x.  So either you're not using CentOS 6 which those instructions are made for or you're not using the apr-util/httpd version that comes with CentOS 6.

If you're not using CentOS 6 then I suggest you go get a version built for your distribution from [WANdisco's download site](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download) (the script that the site you linked to actually is from WANdisco).

If you're using your own httpd version you'll either have to switch or you'll have to build your own copy of Subversion.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar experiences with other applications using this library and Centos 6.x. I have tracked most of the problems down to using the 'minimum install' version of the OS. From what I have been able to determine, the minimum or light install versions of Centos have a tendency to have older versions of the binaries. For example, my version of APR-Utils are 1.3x even though I am using version 6.6.

This is supposedly done for better stability and backward compatibility from what I can find but it causes some headaches if you aren't aware. You may need to use a more 'complete' version of the OS in order for this library to be the latest version, provided you are starting from scratch.