# Apache Error on CentOs fails to start or restart

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, centos, centos7

Apache web server fails to restart.The server has been running well and suddenly failed.
What would be the possible cause for making httpd.service fail to start and what is the solution?

Running `Apachectl configtest` returns symbol lookup error: /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd: undefined symbol: apr_crypto_init

Running `systemctl status httpd.service` :

```
  httpd.service - Web server Apache
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-10-04 22:36:27 CST; 1min 24s ago
  Process: 13030 ExecStop=/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl graceful-stop (code=exited, status=127)
  Process: 3911 ExecStart=/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 851 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 04 22:36:27 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com systemd[1]: Starting Web server Apache...
Oct 04 22:36:27 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com apachectl[3911]: /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd: undefined symbol: apr_crypto_init
Oct 04 22:36:27 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=127
Oct 04 22:36:27 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Web server Apache.
Oct 04 22:36:27 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Oct 04 22:36:27 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Running `journalctl -xe` :

```
Oct 04 22:51:54 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com kernel: net_ratelimit: 75 callbacks suppressed
Oct 04 22:51:56 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com sshd[4063]: Failed password for root from 61.177.172.114 port 36803 ssh2
Oct 04 22:51:56 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com sshd[4065]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.195 port 33236 ssh2
Oct 04 22:51:56 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com sshd[4063]: Received disconnect from 61.177.172.114 port 36803:11:  [preauth]
Oct 04 22:51:56 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com sshd[4063]: Disconnected from 61.177.172.114 port 36803 [preauth]
Oct 04 22:51:56 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com sshd[4063]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=61.177.172.114  user=root
Oct 04 22:51:56 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com sshd[4065]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
Oct 04 22:51:59 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com sshd[4065]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.195 port 33236 ssh2
Oct 04 22:51:59 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com sshd[4065]: Received disconnect from 218.92.0.195 port 33236:11:  [preauth]
Oct 04 22:51:59 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com sshd[4065]: Disconnected from 218.92.0.195 port 33236 [preauth]
Oct 04 22:51:59 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com sshd[4065]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.195  user=root
Oct 04 22:51:59 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com kernel: net_ratelimit: 65 callbacks suppressed
Oct 04 22:52:05 hwsrv-985893.hostwindsdns.com kernel: net_ratelimit: 77 callbacks suppressed
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined symbol: apr\_crypto\_init during Apache restart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048378/undefined-symbol-apr-crypto-init-during-apache-restart)

Comment: Still not working